# unable to cite figure in overlaef iEEE format

Tags: floats, minipage

```
\begin{figure*}
 \begin{minipage}[t]{.47\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Cl.png}%
        \caption{ccccccccccc}%
    \label{Fig3:5dddd}
  \end{minipage}\hfil
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.4\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Rxx.png}%
   \label{Fig:sd}
   \caption{dddddddd}%
 \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

I am unable to cite  `\ref{Fig:sd}` in intext citation.. what can be the reason? I am using the IEEE format

Comment: label has to be after the caption

Comment: As mentioned @DavidCarlisle, label had to be after caption `\begin{figure*}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.47\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{Cl.png}
    \caption{ccccccccccc} 
    \label{Fig3:5dddd}
 \end{minipage}\hfill
 \begin{minipage}[t]{.47\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{Rxx.png} 
    \caption{dddddddd} 
    \label{Fig:sd}
 \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}`